# background color covers dropdown menu bg color

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-color, nav

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SH4X.jpg)

As the title says im having trouble.
Left image is without `bg-color` on `#landing-wrap`, right one is with `bg-color` on `#landing-wrap`.

This is my dropdown menu css code:

```
nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #293133;
    display: block;
    background: #404040;
    color: #fff;
}
```

and this is my div below the nav menu:

```
#landing-wrap {
    background: #00AFAA;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Kantus, welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to assist you to our fullest extent, we need as much information or code relating to the problem as possible. In this case, it would be a big help if you provided us with a working https://codepen.io/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ of your problem. That way we can see the problem for ourselves, debug the issue, and provide you with a solution ASAP. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try with this:

```
#landing-wrap {
background: #00AFAA;
height: 600px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Hope it hleps.

Comment: It won't, unless the element is also positioned. z-index only works on positioned elements.